# Question list on front page showing wrong author for question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On the front page, I am listed as the last author for [image: this question], which simply isn't true. I have never touched that question, look at the revision history.

What gives? Am I misunderstanding something?

[alt text http://pekkagaiser.com/blog/user/files/WTF.PNG](http://pekkagaiser.com/blog/user/files/WTF.PNG)

Comment: That reminds of when I used to work in tech support "No, I never touched that feature, I promise, it wasn't me, no way" (show them an activity log) "Ohh, THAT feature"

Answer (score 4):

You provided an answer there and subsequently deleted it. Your deletion was the last activity that occurred. I believe your answer is between mine and waiwai's.

Comment: Aaaah! That makes sense. Cheers.